# For an algebraic number $a=|a|e^{itπ}$, what can we say about $t$ (where $|a|$ is the absolute value of $a$)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

When  $a=e^{itπ}$ is algebraic , the above discussion only shows that $t$ can not be irrational algebraic.
If $t$  is not rational, then $t$ is a transcendent number

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generality $|a|$ is $1$, because $a/|a|=e^{it\pi}$ is algebraic.

If $t$ is algebraic and irrational then by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), any value of $[e^{it\pi}]^{1/t}$ is transcendental. In particular $-1$ is transcendental, a contradiction. So $t$ is algebraic iff $e^{it\pi}$ is a root of unity.

Comment: ...and $\,e^{\pi i t}\,$ is a root of unity iff $\,t\,$ is rational...+1

Comment: Probably one should first notice that $|a|=\sqrt{a\bar{a}}$ is algebraic.